# ¿Cómo hacer que mi árbol se muestre de forma correcta en C++?

Tags: c++

No se muestra en árbol de la manera normal, quisiera saber como ponerlo correctamente.

**Aquí el código:**

```
void mostrarArbol(Nodo *arbol, int cont) {
if (arbol == NULL) {
    return;
}
else {
    mostrarArbol(arbol->der, cont + 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < cont; i++) {
        cout << "   ";
    }

    cout << arbol->dato << endl;
    mostrarArbol(arbol->izq, cont + 1);

    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido Jose te invito a dar un [tour] para entender el funcionamiento del sitio

Comment: Hola Jose. Lee ese enlace que proporciona @RaulCacacho y además lee [ask]. Has de añadir más informacion como el resultado esperado ya que mencionas *"normal"* pero no dices cómo lo quieres. Pon un ejemplo de entrada de nodos y el resultado que deberian tener. Un saludo